# Access static constant of a subclass from the base class

Tags: c#

I have an `Animal` base class and every subclass needs a static string ID for identification purposes.

So I might have:

```
public class Dog : Animal {
   public static readonly string ID = "dog";
}
```

I do this because I frequently need to use `Dog.ID` throughout my app - in places where I don't yet have an instance.

However, I also need to access this when I have an instance, but I only want to put something like `GetId()` in the base class:

```
public class Animal {
  public string GetId() {
    return ID;
  }
}
```

The problem is, `Animal` would not have access to the static ID field in the children.

Is there a way to do this that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 3):

What about an abstract method?

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public static readonly string ID = "dog";
    public override string GetId()
    {
        return ID;
    }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract string GetId();
}
```

or virtual

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual string GetId()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly... But you could use reflection:

```
FieldInfo id = GetType().GetField("ID", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
return id.GetValue(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a static, set-once *identifier*, it seems like you should use an attribute instead of a `static` field or property:

```
public class AnimalIdAttribute : Attribute
{
     public AnimalIdAttribute(string id)
     {
           Id = id;
     }

     public string Id { get; }
}

public class Animal 
{
     public string Id => this.GetCustomAttribute<AnimalIdAttribute>(true)?.Id;
}

[AnimalId("dog")]   
public class Dog : Animal
{
}
```

Also, if any animal should provide an `Id`, your `Animal` class should be an `abstract` class which should also define an abstract `Id` property:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    // Now you can access Id property implementation 
    // from Animal
    public abstract string Id { get; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override string Id { get; } = "dog";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can do something like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    public static string Id;

    public virtual string GetId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public new static readonly string Id = "dog";

    public override string GetId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

This gives you ability to call Id from Class or an instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you agree to an assumption that `ID` equals to the type name, you can use this approach. It lets you define and inherit ID property in the base class.
Though I agree this might look quite strange at first sight.

```
public class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
    public static readonly string ID = typeof(T).Name;
}

public class Dog : Animal<Dog>
{
}

public class Cat : Animal<Cat>
{
}
```

Expression `Cat.ID` will return `Cat`, and `Dog.ID` will return `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement explicit interface like this

```
public class Animal : IType
{
    private static string _ID = "Animal";

    string IType.ID
    {
        get
        {
            return getID();
        }
    }

    public virtual string getID()
    {
        return _ID;
    }
}
public class Dog : Animal, IType
{
    public static readonly string _dogID = "dog";
    string IType.ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _dogID;
        }
    }
    public override string getID()
    {
        return _dogID;
    }

}


....
// usage
Animal a = new Animal();
Animal d = new Dog();
Console.WriteLine(a.getID());
Console.WriteLine(d.getID());
```